# Voice chat application using Jingle in Android and iPhone

Tags: java, android, objective-c, ios6

i have downloaded webrtc-jingle-client-master application from the following link :https://github.com/lukeweber/webrtc-jingle-client. But, i can't find the lib files for the same.
It is a voice chat application supporting Jingle, extension of XMPP protocol.
Can anyone suggest with some libraries to integrate with it or how to move further with the application ?